# Static code analysis issue

Tags: apex, bestpractice

I have a method where I am fetching the Id from the URl and using page reference method as below.

```
Public test_method() {
    Id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    PageReference returnPage = new PageReference('/lightning/r/Lead/' + ID+ '/view');
}
```

Our static code analysis is giving me Improper Control of Resource Identifiers
('Resource Injection'). Is this a false positive ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [definition](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/99.html):

> The software receives input from an upstream component, but it does
> not restrict or incorrectly restricts the input before it is used as
> an identifier for a resource that may be outside the intended sphere
> of control.

You are using the id that is given as a parameter, to construct a URL. If there is some way something can manipulate what is passed as id, then the warning/error is correct. But I don't think the analyzer has any way of knowing that when it is analyzing this Apex code, so it is raising the warning/error to be on the safe side.

If you are sure that the id can always be trusted, then it's a false positive. Otherwise your Apex code would have to perform some sanity checks on it, to make sure it's a proper id.

Comment: I would declare the variable's data type as Id, which should be foolproof enough.

Comment: Indeed, without specifying it as an Id (and therefore having ID validation applied) in principle any value could be passed as the "id" parameter.